# Getting the content of specific element using YQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, getjson, yql

I use the code below to load a page using [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_javascript) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "http://www.google.com";
  $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +
    "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" +
    encodeURIComponent(url) + "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data) {
      $('#container').html(data.results);
      alert('Finish');
      $('#container2').text($('#container #hplogo').attr('alt'));
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="background-color:#eee;max-height:200px;overflow:scroll;background-color:#eee;">
  All Page
</div>
<div id="container2">
  Specific Content
</div>
```

You can see it loads Google website, but I don't know why it stops before executing ***Alert('Finish');*** command. I want to extend my code to get the content of specific element inside the ***data.results*** after that.

Any help would be appreciated.